# Is it Illegal or Against the Rules to Hit on the Professor?

Tags: graduate-admissions

I know it is very bad for the professor to hit on the students. But what if a student hits on the professor? I know the professor cannot accept such an advance.

Comment: Are you asking whether it is against the rules for a student to hit on a professor or unethical or what?

Comment: @PeteL.Clark The rules

Comment: Then that sounds like a question to ask someone at your specific university.  Written regulations on this sort of thing vary.

Comment: downvote for unhelpful title

Comment: Why so much downvote? I'm not actually planning on doing this.

Comment: One should not downvote questions based on fallacious moral judgements placed on the asker. I am not a student nor a faculty.

Answer (score 2):

The specific regulations concerning a student initiated relationship will vary by institution, from "No. Just no." to "Perhaps after you're not in their class". You should check with your specific institution.

In a more general sense however, it does put the professor in something of an awkward position - at best, you're suggesting hitting on someone who cannot reciprocate or respond.

Comment: Ah yes, for entertainment. I haven't done this nor am I planning on it.

Comment: I think there may be even more variation than your answer suggests: as much as anything, this tests the willingness of the university to explicitly enumerate undesirable behavior.  (Not every instance of poor behavior is explicitly, directly forbidden.)  Here for instance are the rules on student / faculty interactions at my university: https://eoo.uga.edu/focus-on/are-there-any-prohibited-amorous-relationships-among-university-community-members.  It does not **explicitly prohibit** students hitting on faculty: rather it prohibits dating/sexual relationships in certain contexts.

Comment: @PeteL.Clark More interesting is the idea of flirting with the professor to attract attention for the course. Professors aren't always very engaged with the material.

Comment: I am unconvinced flirting with a professor will make them *more* focused on the material.

Comment: @Fomite It only helps if you are also smart.

Comment: @Fomite You attract the attention and THEN input intellectual content. It only works if you are a nerd or "pre-academic".